# Return JSON from Rest server in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I'm trying to return a **JSON** from a **REST** endpoint server.  I've tried using `dom.io.script.get()`, but this is used to access **JSONP**.  `dom.xhrget`, is disallow for those requests on their server.  My workaround in to user jQuery `$.getJSON` to retrieve the JSON object and return it for utilization in **JavaScript**.  Is this possible.  This is my **psuedo code** for this functionality.

url = http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/6?f=pjson

```
    function GetJson(url){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $getJson(url, function(json){
            return json;
        });
        });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is `$.getJSON()` and not `$getJson()`. You cannot `return` from an asynchronous call. So, to do something with the `json` that's returned using the `$.getJSON` function, you need to put it in the anonymous function there:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
  // The scope of json is this. You cannot return this anywhere or set anything.
  // Add your functions or instructions that use `json` here.
});
```